# jquery ui datepicker doesn't update values

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Using the jquery datepicker ui, the value attributes of the associated html fields don't update immediately.

> Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4tXP4/
>
> From the horses mouth:
>   http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/alt-field.html

If you inspect the elements you will see that neither value attributes update.

What' missing with these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/UBMXq/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/3BLwK/9/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/wrCv7/

1 things:

- missing `#`  "altField":"#startDate"
- (optional) i.e. DateFormat might need some attention - I reckon dont use `value` in your hidden input

Hope this helps! `:)`

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#startDate_picker").datepicker({
        "altField":"#startDate",
        "dateFormat":"d M y",
        "altFormat":"Y-m-d",
        "changeMonth":true,
        "changeYear":true
    });
});
```

Comment: @Ashley Indeed, Glad it helped `:)` also you might wanna take a look in the date format but you know better.

Answer (score 4):

if you don't want another input field then use `onSelect` but the `.val` function does not update the `value` attribute, so you need to be a bit more raw

```js
$("#datepicker_start").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, datePicker) {
       $(this).attr('value', dateText);
    }
});
```